# How to enable busybox httpd on Alpine linux image

Tags: busybox, alpine-linux

When trying to run busybox httpd in alpine:latest image it ends with error

`httpd: applet not found`

How can I install httpd applet into Alpine image?

Comment: You cannot. That's a compile-time optional component in busybox. The real question is: why was busybox compiled without httpd...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alpine splits the busybox package, to get `httpd` and other networking tools:

```
apk add busybox-extras
```

Comment: and so my work is done 2 seconds after reading your answer!